# What is the difference between "isOpaque" and "isTranslucent" in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I found

```
navigationController.navigationBar.isOpaque
```

and

```
navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent
```

have an identical effect.

Just wondering if anyone knows what is the difference between those two, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isTranslucent:
A Boolean value indicating whether the navigation bar is translucent (true) or not (false).
isOpaque:
A Boolean value indicating whether the title is empty and an opaque bezel is set.

Answer (score 1):

isTranslucent also affects the way the view interacts with the navigation bar, regarding scrolling underneath or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the **navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent to true**.
It set  navigation bar with an opaque custom background image, the navigation bar will apply a system opacity less than 1.0 to the image.
and If you set the **navigationController.navigationBar.isOpaque to true** then it makes all of your navigation bars opaque

Answer (score 0):

They don't have an identical effect. As a matter of fact you are probably not altering the "isOpaque" property.

This property is only used for drawing optimization purposes and is ignored in system provided classes (see documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622622-isopaque)).

If you use a UIView's "draw:" method to change set the appearance then you should set this property so that the system can optimize how it draws this view.

Regarding the "isTranslucent" property. This one is clearly explained by apple in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/1624928-istranslucent).

> The default value is true. If the navigation bar has a custom
>   background image, the default is true if any pixel of the image has an
>   alpha value of less than 1.0, and false otherwise. If you set this
>   property to true on a navigation bar with an opaque custom background
>   image, the navigation bar applies a system-defined opacity of less
>   than 1.0 to the image. If you set this property to false on a
>   navigation bar with a translucent custom background image, the
>   navigation bar provides an opaque background for the image using black
>   if the navigation bar has  black  style, white if the navigation bar
>   has  default , or the navigation bar’s  barTintColor  if a custom
>   value is defined.